# AppCompatButton background selector

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, selector, drawable

i am trying to make a selector for AppCompatButton background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/cat_title"
    android:textColor="@color/teal_600"
    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/iimfinder_selector"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="9dp"
    android:textStyle=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

this is the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button_default"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button_default"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button_default"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button_default"/>

<!-- When not selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered"/>
</selector>
```

adapter:

```
class ilmcategoriesAdapter(var countryList: List<ilmcategoriesData>, var activity: MainActivity, var listener: OnClickRecyclerChild): RecyclerView.Adapter<ilmcategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
lateinit var context: Context

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ilmcategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context!!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item3, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ilmcategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.eventName.text = countryList[position].name
    Log.d("ggggggggggggggg", countryList.toString())

    holder.eventName.setOnClickListener {


      var CategoryID =   countryList[position].id
        var CategoryIdStr = CategoryID.toString()

        Log.e("fsds","fdfsd32")

        AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters = CategoryID
        listener.myCallback(CategoryIdStr)
    }



}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val eventName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title)


}



interface OnClickRecyclerChild {
    fun myCallback(s: String?)


}

}
```

and trying to achieve this:

[image]

if its selected should show border around it, if not then there will be no border

i tried the above but when i click one it show the border for 1 second then the border disappear, what seems the issue here?

Comment: Do you have any Java code?

Comment: i'm using Kotlin, do i need code for the selector?

Comment: Without it, how are you going to know whether the button was clicked (without `onClick` in the `xml` as well)?

Comment: i'm still new to Kotlin, is there any example for the code that i need to implement in the fragment?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton) and searched online? If not, do that first and come back if you're stuck with code you have tried.

Comment: yes i did search online before i post the question